# What language or languages are spoken in Night City?

Tags: cyberpunk-edgerunners

In the *Cyberpunk: Edgerunners* anime, largely set in the futuristic Night City, the original spoken audio is entirely in Japanese. However, most of the signs that we see are completely in English, although some have a bit of Japanese as well. Furthermore, all the messages that we see—for instance, those that Katsuo sends to David—are completely in English.

In addition, it is not too uncommon for anime to have a sort of translation convention going on: for instance, in *Fullmetal Alchemist*, the language of the characters is implied to be something rather like German.

Which language or languages, then, are the characters meant to be using in-universe? Are they all speaking Japanese with English being the primary language of written communication (as we seem to see)? Are they all speaking English, but "translated" to Japanese for the viewer? Or something else altogether?

Comment: It's not uncommon to see [signs in English in Japan](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/36c2f80951eb4efd941af3f74cb54741cc08cc82/0_1097_7829_4695/master/7829.jpg?width=1900&quality=85&dpr=1&s=none)

Comment: Night City itself is on the west coast of the US between San Francisco and LA; the RPG sourcebooks state that English is the primary language for any Anglo-American, but that every character also knows streetslang, "a universal polyglot of English, French, German, Japanese and a half dozen other languages".

Comment: @Valorum it's not uncommon in many countries; my own for example, where we speak Spanish. It's a kind of snobbery, English seems "classier" for ads. But even then the vast majority of signs should be in the native language, evidenced even in the photo you shared.

Answer (score 0):

### It doesn't matter (but mostly English and Japanese)

The show is based on the "Cyberpunk 2077" game: it has the same styles of clothing, weapons, various GUI interfaces (when paying or hacking), that I believe the answer based on the game is valid:

Night City is on the West Coast of North America, so you could guess that the native language is American English. There are of course minorities speaking their own languages - from popular like Japanese (which seems to be an official language of Arasaka), Chinese or Spanish to more obscure like Creole. But why did I say that it doesn't matter? Because everyone uses automatic translation software that works in real-time. You can see an example of that during the "Double Life" mission

If you play the game with subtitles on, you will notice that this software not always works, as it struggles with slang/curses:

[image]

Or with words placed out of context:

> "cuteness has nothin to do with it, **mi calabatica.**"

Comment: This answer appear to be based on the video game. Is there reason to think that it is the same in the show?

Comment: @Adamant the show IS based on the game - for example, it has the same graphic for various GUI (cash transactions, hacking) as used in game. Also, t is located in Night City, in year 2077, just like the "Cyberpunk" game :) Honestly, the show takes so much from the game stylistic, that I was half expecting to see an inventory screen

Comment: @Adamant the game (after the 1.6 patch) has multiple references to events of the show, and at least one of the NPCs mentions those events happening a year ago. So both are in the same universe, and not enough time passed to change the city's linguistic makeup.